# Print command in chrome doesn't apply css style

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, styles, media

I need to draw a small vertical seperating line in my print document. When i apply it thro the CSS class ,it works pretty well with firefox and IE8, but the styles dont get applied for chrome. The styles are in @media print of my css file.

```
.verticalLine1 
{border:0.5px #B1B1B1;
border-style:solid;
border-top-width:15px;
width:1px;
}
```

Any pointers to solve this problem?

Comment: refer the link (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp)

Comment: How is your css file included on the page?

Comment: @JanHančič <div class="verticalLine1"></div> . This is how the code looks like.

Comment: No. How is your CSS file (not class) included in your HTML.

Comment: added in a javascript on the Print function . var Ref='<link href="' + somepath+ 'styles/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>';' and it is added to the <head> of the print document for reference . This fuction is called on a button click

Comment: Can you try including the stylesheet "the regular way" that is not dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 pathetic days, I couldn't crack up with a proper fix.But had few alternatives

Writing styles inline with the code worked Pretty perfectly. Code looks as below

```
<div style="border:0.5px #B1B1B1;border-style:solid;border-top-width:15px;width:1px;"></div>
```

Since the previous approach is not a great coding practice I was forced to create an image with the above dimensions and I added it as a part of the code.

Thanks to chrome.Atleast it adds images, if not css.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your CSS file:

```
.verticalLine1 {
    visibility: hidden;
    border: 0.5px #B1B1B1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 15px;
    width: 1px;
}
@media print {
    .verticalLine1 {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

and include CSS file **without** `media="screen"` attribute and **without** any JavaScript click event

```
<link href="styles/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: great work around. But it failed with Chrome as chrome did not load any css file.I am not sure why it failed.my chrome version is 19.0.1084.1 and i feel its kind of buggy always

Answer (score 0):

Adding images for borders is never a good idea. Also, you need to keep in mind that chrome truncates the decimal values to closest lower number. Due to this 0.5px will be interpreted as 0px instead. I will suggest use 1px instead of 0.5px. This will remove so many issues.